# Using data sent via AJAX in multiple functions on a WP plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, gravity-forms-plugin

This might be a scope issue but I want to cover all bases. I am successfully sending a value, distance, to an Ajax handler function. Here is the JS:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
        'action':'example_ajax_request',
        'distance' : distance
    },
    success:function(response) {
        // This outputs the result of the ajax request
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I have access to the distance variable in the backend:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );

// Dynamic field population

function example_ajax_request() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax 
    if ( isset($_POST) ) {

        $distance = $_POST['distance'];
        // echo $distance;

    }

   die();
}
```

`$distance` contains the value and I can echo it successfully. But I need to use this value in another function that hooks into gravity forms. I need to dynamically set a gravity forms value (using their  `gform_field_value_$parameter_name` hook). Problem is that I cannot figure out a way to access the `$_POST['distance']` value outside of the Ajax function and the Gravity Forms hook fires before the `$_POST['distance']` is available (my guess).

Is there a way to access the Ajax sent `$_POST` object outside of the handler function in WP? Am I looking at this all wrong? Any suggestions on how I can use that value to dynamically populate a Gravity Forms field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out:

There is no way to use Ajax data in a hook since WP is already loaded. That data is only available in the front end. To that end, you would:

```
    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: {
    'action':'example_ajax_request',
    'distance' : distance
  },
  success:function(response) {
    // This outputs the result of the ajax request
    console.log(response);
    $('#your-GF-ID').val( response ); // This is where you update your GF field 
  },
  error: function(errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

The other option is saving the data in DB and just foregoing Ajax.